# How do a website post to user's twitter status ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter

I have a c# mvc 4 web site,I've created a twitter app on https://dev.twitter.com/apps.
from there I want to have a button on homepage to redirect the user to my app on twitter to confirm access information. after that the web site will do a post to the user twitter saying .. "I've joined the new web site .. "

I'm managed doing the part to redirect the user to allow access information :

```
public ActionResult Login()
        {
            try
            {
                string url = "";
                string xml = "";
                oAuthTwitter oAuth = new oAuthTwitter();

                if (Request["oauth_token"] == null)
                {
                    //Redirect the user to Twitter for authorization.
                    //Using oauth_callback for local testing.
                    Response.Redirect(oAuth.AuthorizationLinkGet());
                }
```

Now I need to make a post on the user status
How do I do that ? is there a c# wrapper for Twitter API 1.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a multi-step process.  First you direct the user to Twitter to authorize the app, and in this redirect you supply Twitter with a call-back URL in your website.  Twitter will then direct the user back to that URL with (or without if they refuse access) a code that you would use to post to Twitter on the user's behalf.

You can simplify a lot of this by using something like [TweetSharp](http://www.nuget.org/packages/TweetSharp/), and the code might look something like this:

```
// This is when the user clicks on a link on your site to use your Twitter app
public ActionResult Twitter()
{
    // Here you provide TweetSharp with your AppID and AppSecret:
    var service = new TwitterService(AppID, AppSecret);

    // Provide TweetSharp with your site's callback URL:
    var token = service.GetRequestToken("http://www.yoursite.com/Home/TwitterCallback");

    // Get the fully-formatted URL to direct the user to, which includes your callback
    var uri = service.GetAuthorizationUri(token);
    return Redirect(uri.ToString());
}

// When twitter redirects the user here, it will contains oauth tokens if the app was authorized
public ActionResult TwitterCallback(string oauth_token, string oauth_verifier)
{
    var service = new TwitterService(AppID, AppSecret);

    // Using the values Twitter sent back, get an access token from Twitter
    var accessToken = service.GetAccessToken(new OAuthRequestToken { Token = oauth_token }, oauth_verifier);

    // Use that access token and send a tweet on the user's behalf
    service.AuthenticateWith(accessToken.Token, accessToken.TokenSecret);
    var result = service.SendTweet(new SendTweetOptions { Status = "I've joined the new web site .. " });

    // Maybe check the "result" for success or failure?

    // The interaction is done, send the user back to your app or show them a page?
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```